# Selenium java, Not Secure: data; displays on Chrome Browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, security, selenium-webdriver

I ran into an issue whereby all the tests both the ones executing perfectly before displays Not Secure: data; on chrome browser.

I have tried all my best yet no solution. I have downloaded latest version of chrome driver and chrome browser of the same version yet not resolved. I have added External selenium jar to my Java build path, yet not resolved.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Hi Tejas! Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for answering this question. Please add some additional context to your code snippet so others can understand it better.